# How to fix AttributeError with ImageTk and Tkinter in python3.6?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Murad/PycharmProjects/OmrTest/images/GUI.py", line 765, in <module>
    obj = Login(master)
  File "C:/Users/Murad/PycharmProjects/OmrTest/images/GUI.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="unnamed.png")
  File "C:\Users\Murad\PycharmProjects\OmrTest\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 89, in __init__
    image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
  File "C:\Users\Murad\PycharmProjects\OmrTest\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 58, in _get_image_from_kw
    return Image.open(source)
  File "C:\Users\Murad\PycharmProjects\OmrTest\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2904, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'unnamed.png'
Exception ignored in: <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x000002A705690748>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Murad\PycharmProjects\OmrTest\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

So I was doing a project in pycharm. how do I Solve this problem?

Comment: maybe you don't have 'unamed .png' in the same directory. try using the absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line 35, init self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="unnamed.png")`

Where is the file `unnanmed.png` located?

Use :

`self.bg= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_path))`

`file_path` should be full or relative path of the file if it is not in the root directory.